# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class not found in load Model in Controller

Tags: php

I have this MVC folder structure:

```
application
-----------catalog
------------------controller
----------------------------ProfileContoller.php
------------------model
----------------------------UserModel.php
------------------view
------------------language
-----------admin
------------------controller
------------------model
------------------view
------------------language
core
---- Controller.php
public
vendor
....
```

Now In ProfileController.php I have:

```
namespace Application\Catalog\Controller;

use Application\Core\Controller as Controller;

use Application\Core\Model\UserModel;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Construct this object by extending the basic Controller class
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * This method controls what happens when you move to /overview/index in your app.
     * Shows a list of all users.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->View->render('profile/index','', array(
            'users' => UserModel::getPublicProfilesOfAllUsers())
        );
    }

}
```

And in UserModel.php I Have:

```
namespace Application\Catalog\Model;

class UserModel
{

    public static function getPublicProfilesOfAllUsers()
    {
        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

        $sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_active, user_has_avatar, user_deleted FROM users";
        $query = $database->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();

        $all_users_profiles = array();

        foreach ($query->fetchAll() as $user) {

            array_walk_recursive($user, 'Filter::XSSFilter');

            $all_users_profiles[$user->user_id] = new stdClass();
            $all_users_profiles[$user->user_id]->user_id = $user->user_id;
            $all_users_profiles[$user->user_id]->user_name = $user->user_name;
            $all_users_profiles[$user->user_id]->user_email = $user->user_email;
            $all_users_profiles[$user->user_id]->user_active = $user->user_active;
            $all_users_profiles[$user->user_id]->user_deleted = $user->user_deleted;
            $all_users_profiles[$user->user_id]->user_avatar_link = (Config::get('USE_GRAVATAR') ? AvatarModel::getGravatarLinkByEmail($user->user_email) : AvatarModel::getPublicAvatarFilePathOfUser($user->user_has_avatar, $user->user_id));
        }

        return $all_users_profiles;
    }
```

And With Composer Psr4 I autoload file using:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Application\\": "application/","Application\\Core\\": "application/core/","Application\\Catalog\\Model\\": "application/catalog/model/"}
    }
    }
```

Now I action When I Need To route my Url:

```
$route->get('/cms/profile/index/', 'Application\Catalog\Controller\ProfileController@index');
```

I see This error  :

> >
>   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Application\Catalog\Controller\UserModel' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\application\catalog\controller\ProfileController.php:25 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Application\Catalog\Controller\ProfileController->index() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\vendor\router\route\system\Route.php(649): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\vendor\router\route\system\Route.php(599): System\Route->callback(Array, Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\public\index.php(150): System\Route->end() #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\application\catalog\controller\ProfileController.php on line 25

Comment: Wrong namespace? `use Application\Core\Model\UserModel;` vs. `namespace Application\Catalog\Model;`

Comment: @kerbholz: Oh. You right.

Answer (score 1):

Here you calling the function with the class name that model class not exist in the controller. `UserModel::getPublicProfilesOfAllUsers()`

use Application\Controller\Model\UserModel as UserModel

or

```
use Application\Controller\Model\UserModel;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    protected $userModel;
    /**
     * Construct this object by extending the basic Controller class
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('UserModel');
    }
```

and you can call as

```
$this->View->render('profile/index','', array(
            'users' => $this->UserModel->getPublicProfilesOfAllUsers())
        );
```

The best is to call the non-static function through the object. In PHP 5.3 we can non-static functions as a statically like static functions but in  PHP 7+ marked it as deprecated and will remove it in future.

Comment: You right But I edit and see this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Application\Catalog\Controller\Application\Catalog\Model\UserModel() in

Comment: Please load as `$this->load->model('UserModel');` then call function as `$this->UserModel->getPublicProfilesOfAllUsers();`

Comment: Please try this

Comment: What's and where load?!

Comment: Please load it in constructor or function where you will model function in COntroller